# Building a list by input() python without setting a number of elements

Tags: python, list, input

i study python on my own in the middle of an ocean with limited access to internet.

I'm thinking of a way to make a list by input() without setting a number of elements in the beginning.
So far i end up with this:

```
list = []
value = None

while value != '':
    value = input()
    list.append(value)
    if value == '':
        del list[-1]
        break

print(list)
```

As i can see, code works fine, i can create a list by input(), but it seems ugly to me.
I found the way 'With handling exception', but it works only for string or int.
Thank you!

Comment: You can use `a = input().split()` and enter space separated Values

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way I would write it:

```
lst = list()
while True:
  value = input()
  if value == "":
    break
  lst.append(value)
```

First, use `while True` to loop forever, with an intention of breaking when certain input is encountered. When `value` is read, check if it is empty. If so, `break`. Otherwise, append `value` to `lst` and continue with the loop.

By the way, I renamed `list` to `lst` to avoid variable shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

Can be written more compactly using the walrus operator (assignment with value):

```
li = list()
while (val := input()):
    li.append(val)
```

This saves the input into `val` and simultaneously evaluates whether it's empty or not, breaking the loop in the former case. It uses the fact that empty strings evaluate to False.

Answer (score 0):

So, [assignment expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) were added for this very sort of pattern:

```
data = []
while (value:= input()):
    data.append(value)
```

Note the assignment expression "walrus operator" `:=` is only available in Python >= 3.8

Otherwise, you'd generally do something like:

```
data = []
value = input()
while value:
    data.append(value)
    value = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you want users to input the element multiple times then the above answers are good.
But just say you want an input of elements using a specific separator(space or comma etc) you can do this in one line.
eg. if you were to take input using a space as separator,
l = [x for x in input().split()] would build your list and
if you were to take input and keep , as a separator you could do something like
l = [x for x in input().split(sep=",")].